# How do I use dijkstra_path in networkx to find the length of the shortest path?

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to find the distance/weight of the shortest path, not only the shortest path. Is there any function in `networkx` to find the distance?

Here is my code:

```
import networkx as nx 
import random

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2, weight = 450)
G.add_edge(2, 1, weight = 450)
G.add_edge(1, 3, weight = 390)
G.add_edge(3, 1, weight = 390)
G.add_edge(1, 4, weight = 550)
G.add_edge(4, 1, weight = 550)
G.add_edge(1, 8, weight = 1310)
G.add_edge(8, 1, weight = 1310)
G.add_edge(2, 3, weight = 300)

node_1=input("Entrer Noeud 1:")
node_2=input("Entrer Noeud  2 :")

# shortest path
print "Le plus court chemin de ",node_1," a ",node_2," est :"
liste=nx.dijkstra_path(G,node_1,node_2)
print (liste) 

# length of the shortest path 
print "la longueur du plus court chemin est "  
print (nx.shortest_path_length(G,source=node_1,target=node_2))
```

Comment: You have a typo in the title. It should be "Dijkstra algorithm". By having correct title, you increasing chances of receiving good answer. I cannot edit title, so I'm just commenting it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the weight field name, in this case it is simply 'weight'.

```
nx.shortest_path_length(G, source=node_1, target=node_2, weight='weight')
```

See the [official documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length) for more info